# Angular Material: How to clear suggestions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

```
<md-autocomplete ng-model="ctrl.searchText"
    md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
    md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
    md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
    md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
    md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
    md-item-text="item.display"
    md-min-length="0"
    placeholder="Start typing your search term here">
```

I have the above `md-autocomplete`.

How can I make the suggestions clear on an action? (By clear I mean remove cached result set so that there are no longer any suggestions). Currently my querySearch function is:

```
function querySearch(query) {
    var results = query ? $this.possibles.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : $this.possibles;
    return results;
}
```

My action is setting `$this.possibles = null` but this still doesn't clear the suggestions. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Could you tell us more about the intended use case? Do you want to close the suggestion box or clear the underlying cache/result set?

Comment: Sorry, yes I'd like to clear the underlying cache/result set. So that I could start from fresh and put new results in.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand: the text in the input field should remain there, right? So it's not an option to just clear `ctrl.searchText`?

Comment: I already have cleared ctrl.searchText in my action. I would also like it to clear the cache of suggestions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to clear the cache, you can only disable it. There was a PR on the material repo a while back, but it has been put on hold: https://github.com/angular/material/pull/7421

So, for now, the only way is to completely disable the cache mechanism. To do that you have to add `md-no-cache="true"` to your autocomplet.

Docs: https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/api/directive/mdAutocomplete

Comment: Thanks a lot, this will suit my needs for now. Thanks again.